# SceneView: Apply multiple materials to the object

Tags: xcode, scenekit, blender

In the Apple Fox project level scene, many objects have applied multiple materials. As far as I understand this is something to do with multiple geometry elements.

How to get multiple geometry elements for single object in Xcode Scene view and apply different materials for every element?

Comment: Blender is used to export object in dae/collada format.

Answer (score 2):

Alright guys, figured it out. I was using Blender, but I suppose similar approach might be relevant to other 3D Creation softwares as well.

Basically you need to do following:

1. Unwrap faces of entire object
2. Add new material to your object
3. Select faces you want to have a texture, select material and click Assign. This specifies that given material is affected to selected faces only
4. Create a new texture image for same selected faces
5. Add new texture image to your material

Repeat 2-4 as needed. Once dae imported into Xcode, you should see multiple materials to your object in Materials Inspector and multiple Geometry Elements in Geometry Inspector.

Now is all about adding texture images and link it to every Material properly.

Comment: Life changing and important advice, even after 3 years. Spot on.